# Delimiting with various criteria

Tags: vba, excel

On an Excel order form, starting at row 84, column A is designated as a Last Name column and column B is designated as a First Name column. Regardless, sometimes these order forms are sent in with the first and last names both in the Last Name column. This code works in most situations. If there are two names separated by a space in column A, it moves them to other columns temporarily and then finally to columns A and B.

```
Sub FirstSpaceLastNameFix()
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A84:A" & LastRow).Select
Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range
Set rng = Selection

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A84"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=True, other:=False, FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Range("A84:A" & LastRow).Cut Destination:=Range("EE1")
Range("B84:B" & LastRow).Cut Destination:=Range("A84")
Range("EE1:EE" & LastRow).Cut Destination:=Range("B84")

End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't account for when a middle name or middle initial is given. Is there some way to make it recognize when there are more than a first and last name in column A? And if so, have it remove the middle name?

Using this code in situations where a middle name is given, it will put the middle name in column A, the first name in column B, and the last name in column C.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid a loop, either using TTC and then deleting the middle cell when there are three, or avoiding TTC and checking the number of names in each row using e.g. Split.

Answer (score 0):

This runs through each row instead of using text to columns.

I think regardless of the approach, you will have problems with names like John Doe III, John Michael Doe where John Michael is the "first name", or sometimes hyphenated last names don't include the hyphen so John Smith Doe where Smith Doe is the "last name".

Otherwise...

```
'"FileWithNames.xls" would have to be matched to your file of course.
Dim wbNames As Workbook: Set wbNames = Application.Workbooks("FileWithNames.xls")
Dim strName As String, strFirst As String, strLast As String, i0 As Long
'Worksheets(1) would also have to be set to match the appropriate sheet.
With wbNames.Worksheets(1)
    For i0 = 84 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        strName = .Cells(i0, 1).Value
        If InStr(strName, " ") > 0 Then
            strFirst = Left$(strName, InStr(strName, " ") - 1)
            strLast = Right$(strName, Len(strName) - InStrRev(strName, " "))
            .Cells(i0, 1).Value = strLast
            .Cells(i0, 2).Value = strFirst
        End If
    Next i0
End With
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything at all when I run it.

Comment: Does the test data you just ran start at row 84? I built a mockup spreadsheet and I'm not running into any issues. Also, I used "Activesheet" above. Maybe it latched onto a different sheet than what you were expecting if you have multiple workbooks open.

Comment: The data does start at row 84. I started with a fresh sheet, and no other Excel windows are open. I do use a Personal macro workbook though, but this new sheet should be the active one.

Comment: I've edited the code above to work with that workbook specifically. Give that a try.